# Does an unoccupied mount count as an ally, for flanking?

Tags: dnd-4e, mounted-combat

Can you use your mount as an ally, for flanking purposes, while dismounted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**,

It's odd that mounts aren't explicitly noted as allies anywhere that I could find.

The *Rules Compendium* p254 notes that all mounts can attack at -2, although few attack on their own.

Mounts are explicitly targeted separately from their rider <sup>(ibid)</sup>.  I find it hard to believe that a DM would not allow the mount to be the target of a beneficial effect like **Shield of Faith**<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=945)</sup> that only targets allies.

Given that, extending all rights as "allies" to the mounts seems entirely reasonable and non-controversial.

Answer (score 10):

If the mount could attack the foe, then it can count as flanking.

Comment: Then, in most cases, I think it would not.  Mount & Rider rules in the Rules Compendium specify that a mount does not typically attack, unless it's specially trained to do so.

Comment: There is a good chance that PCs are going to opt to buy a warhorse instead of a plain riding horse.

Comment: ...unless the riding horse is stumbled upon in an encounter along the way - which is in fact what prompted this query.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the mount has been trained to fight in this capacity, I would say most likely not.  Warhorses are trained to fight while mounted and directed by a rider but typically do not engage in strategic combat and will still flee if left w/o guidance.